# How to hide content after an expiration date using the data attribute? (data-*)

Tags: php, html, attributes

I am wondering if there is a simple way using PHP to hide content after a certain date.

Let's say a page has several `<div>` containers and with different `data-*` attributes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Events</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <header>
        <h1>Events</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="event" data-event-date="2015-05-18">
        <h2>Womens Half Marathon</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="event" data-event-date="2015-05-19">
        <h2>Loop around the lake</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="event" data-event-date="2015-05-20">
        <h2>Walk in the Park 2015</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

Is there an easy way to only show events which have not expired? Any content with an data attribute before `data-event-date="2015-05-19"` should not be visible.

So today, on May 19 2015, the PHP page should only give out this source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Events</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <header>
        <h1>Events</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="event" data-event-date="2015-05-19">
        <h2>Loop around the lake</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="event" data-event-date="2015-05-20">
        <h2>Walk in the Park 2015</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

Any ideas for an easy PHP solution to hide content after an expiration date?

I am really thankful for any help on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a variable and compare it to the current date.  and if so, render the view.  If not, then skip it.

Example:

```
$cut_off_time = strtotime($var);
$compare = time() - $cut_off_time;

if($compare > 1){
    //display view
}
```